# fixedpoint prevent resizing

Tags: python, fixed-point

Is there a way to do fixed point operations in python (base 2, so not the *decimal* package), which has an option for fixing the size of the two fields?

I know of the *fixedpoint* package, but sadly I can't find an option for this.

As example, what behavior is not desired:

```
>>> import fixedpoint
>>> a=fixedpoint.FixedPoint(1, m=2,n=1)
>>> a.m
2
>>> b=a+a+a
>>> b.m      # should still be 2
4
```

I know I could write a wrapper around this and resize every single operation, but there has to be a better way to do this.

Edit: Rephrased question

Comment: The author of this package evidently considers mathematical correctness to be more important than maintaining the specified bit sizes.  I don't see any workaround other than manually resizing after operations.

Comment: "Is there a python package" -- questions seeking library recommendations are off-topic.